# Why does QGIS Profile from Line tool give me the same value for every point?

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I'm trying to make an elevation profile with QGIS's Profile from Line plugin. But when I do, the resulting points all have the same value: -32,767. I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

My elevation data is from [GeoBase.ca](http://geobase.ca) (at 1:50,000 scale). My route line is selected in yellow, below.

As an aside: my route covers two raster files, and I haven't figured out how to render them to the same elevation scale. The top of the map is coloured as low elevation because of mountains to the north. I don't think this is the source of my problem -- when I sample the elevation layers with the Identify Features tool, it reports the elevation changes that I'd expect.

[image: route line]

Here are the options I used with the Profile from Line tool:

[image: profile from line]

Profile from Line makes a new layer. Here is its attribute table. Note that all of the values are the same.

[image: attribute table]

What should I do to get a valid elevation profile? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DEMs appear to be lat/lon. To use the profile from line tool I think you will need to warp them to a projected CRS (in QGIS, Raster -> Projections  -> Warp (Reproject). Nick.